# hide a certain custom field

Tags: custom-post-types

I am new with Wordpress,
I want to hide a custom fields from particular post types and the problem is the custom fields are same for other post types, if I remove the custom fields it will also remove from all post types and I want to hide custom fields for only specific post types.

For example the post types are:

> 1.Package
>
> 2.Group tour
>
> 3.Excursion

and custom fields are

> general info, price info,image,tab 1,tab2, activate itinerary
>   tab.itineary,tab3,activate price tab,price info,include,not
>   included..etc

from post type excursion I want to hide (included and not included).

please help me to achieve this ???

Comment: What do you mean by hiding a custom field? From where? How do you update it then?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Tested locally and it works.

```
// Hide 'included' and 'not included' custom meta fields 
// from the edit 'excursion' post type page.
function my_exclude_custom_fields( $protected, $meta_key ) {

  if ( 'excursion' == get_post_type() ) {

    if ( in_array( $meta_key, array( 'included', 'not included' ) ) ) {
      return true;
    }

  }

  return $protected;
}
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'my_exclude_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks...but in which file i should place this??

Comment: Put it in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Yeah i found it but it didnt work..

Comment: still showing the option of included and not included

Comment: @Kuanl are you sure the custom post type name is exactly spelled like `excursion`? Also make sure you pasted it into the current theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: yeap and i m pasted in function.php into the current themes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
add_filter('is_protected_meta', 'my_is_protected_meta_filter5', 10, 2);
function my_is_protected_meta_filter5($protected, $meta_key) {
    if ( in_array( $meta_key, array( 'para1', 'para2' ) ) ) {
        return true;
    }
        return $protected;
}
```